# Don't use sizeof for T if T is a function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, function-pointers

I have near following struct for detecting if type can be passed by value:

```
template <class T>
struct should_be_passed_by_value {
    static constexpr bool value = 
        std::is_scalar<T>::value || 
        std::is_array<T>::value || 
        std::is_reference<T>::value || 
        (sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*));
};
```

Problem is: when I instantiate it for C-like function pointer or std::function, the compiler says:

```
invalid application of 'sizeof' to a function type
```

(of course).

How can it be modified so that `value` will contain `false`?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Can you give an example of a use where it produces the error message? I tried 'should_be_passed_by_value<int(*)(void)>::value' and it compiled successfully with both Visual Studio 2015 and gcc 4.9.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Clang ( 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 )

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Try `void foo() {}` and then `should_be_passed_by_value<decltype(foo)>::value;`

Comment: That's not a function *pointer* type, that's a function type.

Comment: I know.  Was the only way though in which I could reproduce the error.

Comment: Makes sense. Maybe OP should specialize behavior for function types for the implicit conversion to function pointers...

Comment: @OP can you please show the calling code that produces the error.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work for std::function??  It certainly should!  Maybe you should provide a minimal, complete, example that shows more about how you're doing this.

Comment: Also `should_be_passed_by_value<std::function<void(void)>>::value;` works so not sure what you are using.

Comment: not sure why comments revolt around std::function if author mentioned C-like function, is not it just about enable_if and/or std::is_function ?

Comment: @OlegBogdanov The comments are revolting about both c-style functions and `std::function`. The consensus is that OP's code works fine for function *pointer* types, but not for *function* types, and that no-one knows what he's doing to get failures for `std::function`, and therefore OP needs to provide more information.

Comment: @jaggedSpire now I see, sorry

Comment: Why not `std::is_same<T, void*>::value` instead of the `sizeof` check?

Comment: @AndyG, I guess author really wanted to compare size to ptr size, not check if its void* ?

Comment: Note: you're saying arrays and references should be passed by value? How can they be? Either your trait is confusingly named, or there's something off in your logic.

Comment: @hvd yes, `std::is_array` is checking for `T[]` which is actually a pointer, and references (`T = U&`) can be passed by "value" too (i.e. by `U&`).

Comment: @vladon Passing a pointer to the first element of an array isn't passing that array by value (it allows modifying the array's contents), it's only passing that pointer by value, and I'd say passing `int &` is passing `int` by reference, not passing `int &` by value. Hence my "confusingly named" comment. :) That aside, more relevant for you, `T[]` would fail as well. `T[N]` would work, but taking the size of an array of unspecified length will cause a compile-time error as well (`should_be_passed_by_value<int[]>::value`). If you want this to work, skypjack's answer may be easier to tweak.

Comment: Perhaps in the sizeof comparison, you can use `sizeof(std::conditional_t<!std::is_function<T>::value, T, void*[2]>::type) <= sizeof(void*)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can it be modified so that value will contain false?

Any problem can be solved with an extra layer of indirection. We have some of these built in already. Basically, you want your smallness check to only be used when `T` is not a function. There's a metafunction for that already: `std::conditional`. We can use it to delay evaluation.

The smallness check, we separate out into its own metafunction:

```
template <class T>
struct is_small
    : std::integral_constant<bool, (sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*))>
{ };
```

And then we can rewrite your condition as:

```
template <class T>
struct should_be_passed_by_value {
    static constexpr bool value = 
        std::is_scalar<T>::value || 
        std::is_array<T>::value || 
        std::is_reference<T>::value || 
        std::conditional_t<
            std::is_function<T>::value,
            std::false_type,
            is_small<T>>::value;
};
```

This way, `is_small<T>` is only instantiated if `T` is not a function.

Answer (score 4):

> How can it be modified so that value will contain false?

It follows a possible implementation for `should_be_passed_by_value` (actually a minimal, working example):

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<functional>

template <class T, typename = void>
struct should_be_passed_by_value: std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct should_be_passed_by_value
<T, std::enable_if_t<
    (std::is_scalar<T>::value ||
    std::is_array<T>::value ||
    std::is_reference<T>::value || 
    (sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*)))
>>: std::true_type {};

void f() {}

int main() {
    static_assert(should_be_passed_by_value<int>::value, "!");
    static_assert(should_be_passed_by_value<char>::value, "!");
    static_assert(not should_be_passed_by_value<std::function<void(void)>>::value, "!");
    static_assert(not should_be_passed_by_value<void(void)>::value, "!");
    static_assert(should_be_passed_by_value<void(*)(void)>::value, "!");
}
```

The basic idea is to rely on a partial specialization.
Moreover, you don't really have to define your own `value` data member. Because you are using C++14, `should_be_passed_by_value` can inherit directly from `std::false_type` and `std::true_type`.

By default, your type `T` should not be passed by value (`should_be_passed_by_value` inherits from `std::false_type`).
If `T` doesn't pass all the checks, the specialization is discarded because of how `std::enable_if_t` works. Therefore the primary template is picked up and that means that `T` shouldn't be passed by value.
If `T` passes all the checks, `std::enable_if_t` is `void` and the specialization is preferred over the primary template. Note that the specialization inherits from `std::true_type` and that means that `T` should be passed by value in this case.

As you can see from the example, `std::function`, function types and all the other things are treated easily and transparently, with no additions to your original expression.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to reproduce the problem exactly as you describe it, but if I understand the question correctly you can use [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) to cleanly solve this problem. The following example compiles with Visual Studio 2015 and gcc 4.9.

```
#include <type_traits>

// Non-function types
template <class T>
struct should_be_passed_by_value 
{
    static constexpr bool value = 
        std::is_scalar<T>::value || 
        std::is_array<T>::value || 
        std::is_reference<T>::value || 
        (sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*));
};

// Function type
template <class Return, class ... Args>
struct should_be_passed_by_value<Return(Args...)> 
{
    static constexpr bool value = false; // What value for functions?
};
```

Here are some use case that compile

```
// All of these use cases compile
#include <array>
const auto u = should_be_passed_by_value<std::array<int, 10>>::value;
const auto v = should_be_passed_by_value<int*()>::value;
const auto w = should_be_passed_by_value<int()>::value;
const auto x = should_be_passed_by_value<int(int)>::value;
const auto y = should_be_passed_by_value<int*>::value;
const auto z = should_be_passed_by_value<int>::value;
```

Comment: This is template specialization though, not sfinae.

Comment: Variadic functions need a separate specialisation: `should_be_passed_by_value<int(...)>::value`. Formally, C-language-linkage functions need a separate specialisation too, but common compilers don't implement this. In practise, non-standard calling conventions need a separate specialisation too, but there is no standard way for specifying this. It would perhaps be better to detect (using SFINAE) a failure to use `sizeof`, and in that case, cover all options at once.

Comment: ... and it needs a `const`, `const &`, `const &&`, and a bunch of other specializations. That's not really clean anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer (As its been mentioned in comments it's not clear what does not work for you for std::function, it is supposed to)

You could combine[enable_if_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [is_function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function) to divide type space into two parts, functions and 'the rest' :

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <class T, class Enable = void>
struct should_be_passed_by_value; // primary case that we will never hit

template <class T>
struct should_be_passed_by_value<T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_function<T>::value>>
{
  static constexpr bool value = false; // case 0
};

template <class T>
struct should_be_passed_by_value<T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_function<T>::value>>
{
  static constexpr bool value =
      std::is_scalar<T>::value || // case 1
      std::is_array<T>::value || // case 2
      std::is_reference<T>::value || // case 3
      (sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void *)); /// case 4
};

void testF(){};

int main()
{
  std::function<void()> f;
  std::cout << "should_be_passed_by_value1 " << should_be_passed_by_value<decltype(testF)>::value << std::endl; // result 0, case 0

  std::cout << "should_be_passed_by_value1 " << should_be_passed_by_value<decltype(5)>::value << std::endl; // res 1, case 1

  std::cout << "should_be_passed_by_value1 " << should_be_passed_by_value<char[42]>::value << std::endl; // res 1, case 2

  std::cout << "should_be_passed_by_value1 " << should_be_passed_by_value<int&>::value << std::endl; // res 1 , case 3

  struct Small {char _{2};};
  std::cout << "should_be_passed_by_value1 " << should_be_passed_by_value<Small>::value << std::endl; // res 1, case 4

  struct Big {char _[16];};
  std::cout << "should_be_passed_by_value1 " << should_be_passed_by_value<Big>::value << std::endl; // res 0, case 4


}
```